# How do I assign a custom element's text contents to a template slot?

Tags: javascript, native-web-component

I'm creating some web components and would like to insert the contained text into a template slot. I'd like to make it slottable as opposed to simply copying their value so the browser can naturally handle changes to the text instead of having to pass it through the component itself.

According to MDN textNodes *are* slottable, however I can't find any real means of doing this aside from the deprecated  element from v1. (textNodes do not support attributes, so I can't simply assign it a slot that way, and .assignedSlot() is read-only.) Support outside the documentation is pretty minimal, although this is to be expected from such a new technology.

```
<my-element>some text</my-element>

<template>
 <h3><slot name="label"></slot></h3>
 <p>Derp</p>
</template>
```

Using this as a simplified example, I'd like `some text` to appear in the `label` slot, and get updated accordingly when the markup changes.
Is there a good/integrated way to do this? Will I have to resort to a mutationObserver?

Comment: Not so much an answer as an update- I have managed to implement this using a self-observing mutationobserver, although I'm still looking for a more elegant method if possible.

Comment: can't you use an unnamed slot?

Comment: This does work, thanks! I didn't see this in the documentation anywhere, so thanks for bringing this to my attention!

Answer (score 3):

You cannot assign a text node via a named `<slot>` simply because a named slot require to match an element with a `slot` attribute.

As a consequence, you'll need to embed your text in a  element at least:

```
<my-element>
    <span slot="label">some text</span>
</my-element>
```

Alternatly, an unnamed `<slot>` can match all the light DOM content, including text nodes.